# Restrict users from accessing websites from a AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip, access-control, restrict

I have an application hosted on AWS EC2 instance. Few developers access the instance via shell to do maintenance on the application. How can I limit them from accessing/downloading content from other websites through the EC2 instance? My end goal is to allow developers to access the instance via shell to do code management/deployment/maintenance and nothing else. Developers may change over time so I'm not sure if outgoing rules can be defined based on IP addresses. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Outgoing rules should not trouble changing developers since those will be covered by incoming rules. Setting up the security group to not allow external communication is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One more question. If I restrict all HTTP and HTTPS outbound rules, will that affect their ability to do git operation/library updates?

Comment: yes, absolutely, those will not longer be possible. what specifically are you trying to restrict and for what reason? You can restrict access to only specific outbound IPs but you then need to get clear about which ones, etc.

Comment: Got it. My motive is to make sure developers use the server for operations related to application maintenance which would include git, library updates, etc. At the same time restrict access/download capabilities to/from all other websites for all developers.